# Smooth scroll to form and focus on textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

After clicking link I'm trying to achieve 3 things

- make it smooth scroll down to #form
- make textarea focused, so that one can immediately write a message
- maintain some extra top margin beacuse I have fixed top bar on my site.

  ```
  <a class="link" href="#form">Go to form</a>
  <div id="form" style="padding-top: 100px; margin-top: -100px;">
      <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
  ```

I used this for top margin:

```
padding-top: 100px; margin-top: -100px;
```

I'm trying jQuery but can't get all features to work simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you can scroll to element - offset + animation with jQuery:

```
 $("#clickedElement").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#textAreaFocused").offset().top-200
    }, 2000, function(){$( "#textAreaFocused" ).focus();});
});
```

Of course, this is just an example you can work with. You will need to adjust values to fit your style. I used -200 as an example.